# Does FCM work well with AWS SNS?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am developing a push notifications architecture for our app. I am planning to use AWS-SNS with APNS and GCM. Google now recommends to use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) instead of GCM for new apps. I wanted to understand if FCM is compatible with SNS or there can be some issues ? Are there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, FCM is backwards compatible with GCM (and thus SNS). I've written a small guide for FCM on SNS in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300450/fcm-with-aws-sns/38623482#answer-38626398) as there are a few gotchas.

The FCM API allows a superset of GCM functionality if you use it directly but functionality wise you don't lose access to anything already available in SNS. It's also [nice and easy to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611592/does-firebase-manage-user-data-like-device-token-bundle-id-etc-at-their-own-whe#answer-38627836).

Comment: I got an email recently from Google that they are retiring GCM in 2019, does this affect how it works currently with Amazon SNS?

Comment: Not any more GCM server is shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Yes FCM is compatible with SNS, you need to be a bit careful about the payload as the format is a bit different.

For detailed tutorial read the following [article](https://medium.com/@naren_mehra/send-your-android-clients-notifications-using-fcm-and-amazon-sns-38874df9c100).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly while it is recommended to use FCM, GCM is still being supported and thus any service built on GCM should continue to work as expected. Also currently (this may change in the future) from a sending perspective there is no difference between FCM and GCM.

Comment: Not anymore GCM server shutdown May 29th