# FCM with AWS SNS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `AWS` resources for my android project, I am planning to add push notification service for my project with `AWS SNS`.there are few questions bothering me much. I did not find any questions regarding these, except one or two but with unclear explanations.

1.Does `AWS` support `FCM`? `SNS` work with `GCM`. But Google recommends to use FCM instead of `GCM`. I did not find `AWS` supporting `FCM`.

2.Do `AWS` store messages (or data) into their databases even after sending push notifications?

3.I tried putting FCM api key in SNS application platform, it is showing invalid parameters why?

Comment: SNS does not yet support FCM, it uses a deprecated version of GCM. Where are you getting the API key from?

Comment: What i tried was, I tried to put api key of FCM in SNS and it did not work, After reading the doc in AWS(SNS) they mentioned to put server key. I tried it worked well. I am able to send push notifications via SNS for FCM. Don't know the reason exactly why it worked. Are you sure that SNS does not support FCM currently?

Comment: It is correct that the server key is required to send GCM (now FCM) messages. On the client side (mobile device) GCM and FCM are generally the same so both will receive messages in an expected fashion. However there are some FCM features that will not work, eg: topic messaging.

Comment: is it possible to use sns topics with fmc? thank you for such an awesome answer

Comment: whats the benefit to using SNS in first place? shouldn't FCM be enough?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

FCM is backwards compatible with GCM. The steps for setting up FCM on AWS are identical to the [GCM set up procedure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html#create-project-gcm) and (at least for the moment) FCM works transparently with GCM and SNS with respect to server-side configuration.

*However*, if you are sending `data` payloads to the Android device they will not be processed unless you implement a [client side service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`. The default JSON message generator in the AWS console sends `data` messages, which will be ignored by your app unless the aforementioned service is implemented. To get around this for initial testing you can provide a custom `notification` payload which will be received by your device (as long as your app is not in the foreground)

There are [GCM-FCM migration instructions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) provided by Google however the changes you need to make are predominantly on the App side.

The steps you need to follow to test GCM/FCM on your app with SNS are:

1. Create a [Platform Application in SNS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/v2/home?region=ap-southeast-2#/applications), selecting Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) as the **Push Notification Platform**, and providing your [Server API key](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) in the **API key** field.
2. Select the Platform Application and click the **Create platform endpoint** button.
3. Provide the InstanceID (**Device Token**) generated by your app. You must extend the `FirebaseInstanceIDService` and override the `onTokenRefresh` method to see this within your Android App. Once you [have done this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#retrieve-the-current-registration-token), uninstall and reinstall your app and your token should be printed to the Debug console in Android Studio on first boot.
4. Click the **Add endpoint** button.
5. Click on the ARN link for your platform application.
6. Select the newly created Endpoint for your device and click the **Publish to endpoint** button.
7. Select the JSON **Message Format**, and click the **JSON message generator** button.
8. Enter a test message and click the **Generate JSON** button
9. Now comes the "gotcha part".

The message that is generated by SNS will be of the form:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

As we mentioned earlier, `data` payloads will be ignored if no service to receive them has been implemented. We would like to test without writing too much code, so instead we should send a `notification` payload. To do this, simply change the JSON message to read:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"title\": \"test title\", \"body\": \"test body\" } }"
}
```

(For more information about the JSON format of an FCM message, see the [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).)

Once you have done this, make sure your app is not running on the device, and hit the **Publish Message** button. You should now see a notification pop up on your device.

You can of course do all this programmatically through the Amazon SNS API, however all the examples seem to use the `data` payload so you need to keep that in mind and generate a payload appropriate to your use case.

Comment: Brilliant answer, thanks.  It's worth noting that the json has some depth in regards to configuration options - see https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options - though I haven't tested any FCM-specific functionality.

Comment: `data` messages is working fine using sns even if the client app doesn't implement FCM but GCM. In my app i have not upgraded to FCM in client side but FCM using SNS works fine for `data` messages too. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: SNS uses GCM so if you are using the GCM client it should behave as normal (up until the point that Google decides to retire GCM). This question is more to do with FCM support on AWS (which is supported via backwards compatibility on the Google API side)

Comment: is it possible to use sns topics with fmc? thank you for such an awesome answer

Comment: Welcome - yes, you can individually subscribe mobile push (ie. GCM->FCM) endpoints to a SNS topic as normal, however this would generate a large number of messages within AWS.

If you're using FCM client side another alternative is to use FCM Topics or User Segments which will only travel through Google's servers

Comment: I've added the notification field as explained in your answer, but RemoteMessage.getNotification() is still null in my app's FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(). Any solution for this ?

Comment: It seems that this unfortunately is not working anymore since google GCM was deprecated on last april, I am contacting aws support to confirm what is their position regards this. Does anyone has issues with SNS FCM notifications?

Comment: Do you know why I received 2 notifications while using SNS? One with expo logo and one with a white box logo

Comment: Hi, I have an app and backend code that currently uses FCM and the push messaging works fine. But I have been deploying it to local server until now. But now I want to deploy it to AWS. Is it really necessary to use SNS? I dont want to sned messages using an interface on AWS, i want my existing flow to work on AWS.

Comment: Just leaving this here because I missed it the first time: You have to encode the value of `GCM` as a JSON string, instead of including it as an object value directly. So you'll have JSON encoded in JSON.

Comment: you are a hero. i am trying everything for about 1 week only your message saved us.

Answer (score 15):

Now you can go to your firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) select your project, click the gear icon and choose project settings, then click on the cloud messaging tab...

You'll see the legacy Server Key which is the GCM API Key and you'll have the option to generate new Server Keys which are the FCM versions

SNS will accept both versions but their menu option is still categorizing it under GCM

Here is picture for your reference:

[image]

Note that you can "accidentally" remove your Server Keys but the Legacy server key is not deletable. Also, if you click the add server key button, you'll get a new server key BELOW the first one, WITH NO WARNING! ...Nice job Google ;)

Answer (score 8):

One more additional note to Nathan Dunn's great answer.
How to send data with the notification from SNS to Firebase.

We need to add data to the Json (inside the notification):

```
{
    "default": “any value", 
     "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \”message body\”, \”title\”: \”message title \”, \"sound\":\"default\" } , \"data\" : {\”key\" : \”value\", \”key2\" : \”value\” } }”
}
```

In your FirebaseMessagingService implementation (Xamarin example)

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
{

    try
    {

        var body = message?.GetNotification()?.Body;
        var title = message?.GetNotification()?.Title;
        var tag = message?.GetNotification()?.Tag;
        var sound = message?.GetNotification()?.Sound;

        var data = message?.Data
        foreach (string key in data.Keys)
        {
            // get your data values here
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the FCM token?

Comment: how can I send an image URL  in the payload

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use solution with notification payload instead of data, but I did not receive push notifications on the mobile device. I found this tutorial https://youtu.be/iBTFLu30dSg with English subtitles of how to use FCM with AWS SNS step by step and example of how to send push notifications from AWS console and implement it on php with aws php sdk. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Just an additional note to Nathan Dunn's Answer: to add sound use the following JSON message

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"text\": \"test message\",\"sound\":\"default\" } }"
}
```

Comment: how can I send an image URL in the payload

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out how to send the notification with the right payload (publish to topic). So I will put it here.

```
private void PublishToTopic(string topicArn)
{
    AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient snsClient = 
           new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
    PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest();
    publishRequest.TopicArn = topicArn;
    publishRequest.MessageStructure = "json";
    string payload = "\\\"data\\\":{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Test \\\"}";
    publishRequest.Message = "{\"default\": \"default\",\"GCM\":\"{" + payload + "}\"}";
    PublishResponse publishResult = snsClient.Publish(publishRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does support FCM as all previous code has been migrated from GCM to FCM. Below article explains in detail.

[Article Published by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/the-end-of-google-cloud-messaging-and-what-it-means-for-your-apps/)

Answer (score -3):

To answer the questions:

1. AWS SNS does support FCM.
2. No AWS does not store messages after sending push notifications.

For a detailed tutorial on setting up FCM with SNS please read [this article.](https://medium.com/@naren_mehra/send-your-android-clients-notifications-using-fcm-and-amazon-sns-38874df9c100)