# Send JSON data payload to FCM by AWS SNS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I am trying to send a json message that has `data` payload from AWS SNS to FCM. Per another thread, the JSON message that I send from SNS should be in the form:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

Within my Android App, I have extended the `FirebaseMessagingService` and overrode the `OnMessageReceived` method to handle incoming push notifications.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        string messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body; //Fails here
        int custom1;
        string custom2 = string.Empty;

        try { custom1 = Convert.ToInt32(message.Data["custom1"]); }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e) { custom1 = -1; }

        try { custom2 = message.Data["custom2"].ToString(); }
        catch (KeyNotFoundException e) { custom2 = "err"; }

        PublishNotification(messageBody, custom1, custom2);
    }
```

When I send a custom notification through SNS using the JSON message I have written above, the message is received successfully. However, when I attempt to process the JSON, it fails once it reaches `message.GetNotification().Body`. The error I receive tells me the body was not included in the JSON message.

My question is, what is the correct JSON message when sending `data` payloads from AWS SNS to FCM.

I have tried the following alternatives as well, to no avail:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"text\": \"test message\" } }"
}

{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"body\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Is **message** null by chance?  Or does it properly include other data?

Comment: No, message is not null. It contains other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `string messageBody = message.GetNotification().Body;` to `messageBody = message.Data["message"].ToString();` and successfully managed to retrieved the contents of the message body.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300450/fcm-with-aws-sns), the message that is generated by SNS Will be of the form:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

Since `data` payloads will be ignored if no service to receive them has been implemented, instead we should send a `notification` payload. To do this, simply change the JSON message to read:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"text\": \"test message\" } }"
}
```

For more information, you can check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626398/5832311) from the given link.