# How to send Firebase Cloud Message with AWS SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I send Firebase push messsages like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/37845174#37845174) as [Data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options). Its a simple REST POST call to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Is ther [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300450/fcm-with-aws-sns/38626398#38626398) to send it in the same way with AWS SNS ?

Comment: I think you answered your own question with that link to the other FCM question.