# Send push notification via SNS and GCM to android

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have configured app and services, I followed the article but with GCM instead FCM https://medium.com/@thexap/show-push-notifications-on-react-native-app-a613a5a2c159
When I try publish message via **SNS** -> **Applications** -> **publish to endpoint**, I have succeeded message : 
 [image] 
 but GCM traffic is empty 
 [image] 
and I don't get any notification in my phone(background and foreground) onNotification handler is never called.

Comment: I think you need to implement client side service to be able to send data loads in your android device. You can follow this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300450/fcm-with-aws-sns/49149156) for a more detailed explanation about the processes you need to do to process your data in your android devices. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the amazon's outdated SNS documentation.

I have changed the payload format and it works for me.

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"hello....\", \"title\": \"title123\" } }"
}
```